# Store SmtpSection in database

Tags: c#, serialization, smtp

I would like to pull the "configuration/system.net/mailSettings/smtp" section from the database instead of from the .config file.  Is this possible?

I receive the following exception

> There was an error reflecting type 'System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection'.
>
> You must implement a default accessor on System.Configuration.ConfigurationLockCollection because it inherits from ICollection.

When I attempt the following code

```
string configFromDb = GetSmtpSectionFromDb();
SmtpSection smtpSettings = null;
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(configFromDb)) {
    using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader)) {
        var x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SmtpSection)); // error occurs here!
        smtpSettings = (SmtpSection)x.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is not possible.  Instead of storing the SmtpSection as an XML blob in the database, I am now storing the individual field values.  It's not as "cool," but it accomplishes the goal.